# Bug in um-olsr for NS 2.34?

Tags: ns2

I think there is a bug in `OLSR::degree()` method:

This method calculates the number of symmetric neighbors of node y, **EXCLUDING** all the members of N.

I think

```
OLSR_nb_tuple* nb_tuple =
state_.find_nb_tuple(nb2hop_tuple->nb_main_addr());
```

should be

```
OLSR_nb_tuple* nb_tuple =
state_.find_nb_tuple(nb2hop_tuple->2_hop_addr());
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes friend, you're right. this is a bug. The correct line is:

```
OLSR_nb_tuple* nb_tuple =
state_.find_nb_tuple(nb2hop_tuple->2_hop_addr());
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm using UM-OLSR version 0.8.8 and the fix you guys gave did not compile, the correct way to fix the bug in UM-OLSR version 0.8.8  is:

```
OLSR_nb_tuple* nb_tuple =
state_.find_nb_tuple(nb2hop_tuple->nb2hop_addr());
```